# How do you make a list of turtles in python?

Tags: python, list, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to make a list of turtles and then use append to extend the list and add more turtles. I keep getting t does not support indexing if I attempt to declare t as a list and call it and if I try to use append, my program freezes. I'm using repl.it
Things I've tried so far:

```
t = [turtle.Turtle(),turtle.Turtle()]

t = turtle.Turtle[2]

t.append(turtle.Turtle())
```

None of these have worked.

Edit: I just realized my error and now I feel dumb. just 20 lines down from

```
t = [turtle.Turtle(),turtle.Turtle()]
```

I had the variable declaration:

```
t = 3000
```

Comment: what is this for `t = turtle.Turtle[2]`

Comment: to create an instance use `turtle.Turtle()`

Comment: I doubt very much that you can use turtle at all on repl.it.

Comment: `t = [turtle.Turtle(),turtle.Turtle()]` works for me to create a list of two turtles on python 2.7

Comment: t = [turtle.Turtle(),turtle.Turtle()] doesn't work for me. It seems to be recognizing it as an int. 'int' does not support indexing. Also I put a () after Turtle in my code, just forgot to do it here for some reason. Fixed.

Comment: That code could not possibly produce that error. Please show *exactly* what you wrote when you got that message.

Comment: I feel so stupid right now... I had another variable defined as t...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this to make your turtles:

```
Python 3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 23 2016, 08:06:12) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import turtle
>>> turtle.resetscreen()
>>> turtles = []
>>> for _ in range(10):
    turtles.append(turtle.Turtle())


>>> for offset, my_turtle in enumerate(turtles):
    my_turtle.right(offset * 10)
    my_turtle.forward(100)


>>>
```

The example shows how to create ten turtles, how to rotate them, and how to move them forward.

Comment: In my situation a list would work best since it would simplify having multiple turtles with multiple attributes (each turtle having a velocity and acceleration). If it's impossible to create a list with turtles I can probably do this but if you or anyone else knows how to create a normal list with turtles I would really be grateful.

Comment: What do you not understand about this line? `turtles = [turtle.Turtle() for _ in range(10)]`

Comment: Can I use something similar to append to increase its length one at a time?

Comment: The example has been changed to use `append` but should not be prefered.